# Flutter/Firebase : I want to update existing values, but new values are being created

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I'm working on a flutter project and this is my code :

```
    String vl = store.reference().child("Volunteers/Aadithya").push().key;
    vlRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("Volunteers/Aadithya");
    vlRef.child(vl).update({
      "Contributions": int.parse(count)+1,
    }).then((_) {
    }).catchError((onError) {
      Scaffold.of(context)
          .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text(onError)));
    });
```

`Contributions` is a data record inside `Aadithya`. I need to update its value alone. But what happens is, a new sub-record is being created inside `Aadithya`, with `contributions` being its data type

Please help:

[image: Database]

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of your database structure ?

Comment: Sure. I have updated

Comment: Hey, I've posted an answer. If that was helpful you can accept it by clicking the tick icon so others will know it is resolved else feel free to ask further queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding it to a child with random ID. You don't need the push key. Try this:

```
vlRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("Volunteers/Aadithya");
vlRef.update({
  "Contributions": int.parse(count)+1,
}).then((_) {

}).catchError((onError) {
  Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text(onError)));
});
```

`.child(vl)` means you are adding another child node with that value.